# How do I convert a date time into a time with hh:mm:ss am/pm

Tags: t-sql, powerbi, powerquery

I am trying to create a fact table for Power BI.  In doing so I want to get my date/time fields put together and create a separate Date and Time field for a separate date dimension and time dimension.

However, I need the field to be HH:MM:SS AM/PM and to be pulled into Power BI as a Time field for the Time dimension.  So far my attempts have PBI pulling it in as Text.  When I try to adjust it on the Power BI Side I get an error as I'm using DirectQuery and can't format the field there.

This is the time dimension blog I'm trying to use to get a Time dimension in Power BI:

https://radacad.com/script-for-creating-time-table-in-power-bi-with-hours-minutes-and-seconds-buckets

I have tried the following:

```
CAST(FORMAT(Create_DateTime,'hh:mm:ss tt') AS TIME) AS Create_Time

CONVERT(char(10), Create_DateTime, 108) as Create_Time 

CAST(Create_DateTime AS TIME) AS Create_Time
```

The only one that POwer BI recognizes as a Time field is where I simply cast as Time.  However, that gives me a 24 hour time with MS's.  The format as hh:mm:ss tt works and gives me the format I want... but Power BI recognizes it as text.  Which I can't change on the Power BI Side.

Barring be able to switch this to a time I am open to changing my power Query to a 24 hour time.  But am unsure as to how to change it as well.  Below is the current power query I'm using as my time dimension.

```
let
    Source = List.Times(#time(0,0,0),24*60*60,#duration(0,0,0,1)),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Converted to Table",{{"Column1", "Time"}}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns",{{"Time", type time}}),
    #"Inserted Hour" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Hour", each Time.Hour([Time]), Int64.Type),
    #"Inserted Minute" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Hour", "Minute", each Time.Minute([Time]), Int64.Type),
    #"Inserted Second" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Minute", "Second", each Time.Second([Time]), type number),
    #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Second", "AM/PM", each if [Hour] < 12 then "a.m." else "p.m."),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Conditional Column",{{"AM/PM", type text}}),
    #"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Changed Type1", "Time", "Time - Copy"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Duplicated Column",{"Time - Copy"}),
    #"Duplicated Column1" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Hour", "Hour - Copy"),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Duplicated Column1",{{"Hour - Copy", "Hour label"}}),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns1",{{"Hour label", type text}}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type2",{"Hour label"}),
    #"Inserted Prefix" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "Prefix", each "0" & Text.From([Hour], "en-NZ"), type text),
    #"Renamed Columns2" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Inserted Prefix",{{"Prefix", "Hour Label"}}),
    #"Extracted Last Characters" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Renamed Columns2", {{"Hour Label", each Text.End(_, 2), type text}}),
    #"Inserted Prefix1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Extracted Last Characters", "Prefix", each "0" & Text.From([Minute], "en-NZ"), type text),
    #"Renamed Columns3" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Inserted Prefix1",{{"Prefix", "Minute Label"}}),
    #"Extracted Last Characters1" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Renamed Columns3", {{"Minute Label", each Text.End(_, 2), type text}}),
    #"Inserted Prefix2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Extracted Last Characters1", "Prefix", each "0" & Text.From([Second], "en-NZ"), type text),
    #"Renamed Columns4" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Inserted Prefix2",{{"Prefix", "Second Label"}}),
    #"Extracted Last Characters2" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Renamed Columns4", {{"Second Label", each Text.End(_, 2), type text}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Extracted Last Characters2", "Index", 0, 1),
    #"Renamed Columns5" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Added Index",{{"Index", "TimeKey"}}),
    #"Inserted Modulo" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns5", "Modulo", each Number.Mod([Hour], 12), type number),
    #"Renamed Columns6" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Inserted Modulo",{{"Modulo", "Hour Bin 12"}}),
    #"Inserted Integer-Division" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns6", "Integer-Division", each Number.IntegerDivide([Hour], 8), Int64.Type),
    #"Renamed Columns7" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Inserted Integer-Division",{{"Integer-Division", "Hour Bin 8"}}),
    #"Inserted Integer-Division1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns7", "Integer-Division", each Number.IntegerDivide([Hour], 6), Int64.Type),
    #"Renamed Columns8" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Inserted Integer-Division1",{{"Integer-Division", "Hour Bin 6"}}),
    #"Inserted Integer-Division2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns8", "Integer-Division", each Number.IntegerDivide([Hour], 4), Int64.Type),
    #"Renamed Columns9" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Inserted Integer-Division2",{{"Integer-Division", "Hour Bin 4"}}),
    #"Inserted Integer-Division3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns9", "Integer-Division", each Number.IntegerDivide([Hour], 3), Int64.Type),
    #"Renamed Columns10" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Inserted Integer-Division3",{{"Integer-Division", "Hour Bin 3"}}),
    #"Inserted Integer-Division4" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns10", "Integer-Division", each Number.IntegerDivide([Hour], 2), Int64.Type),
    #"Renamed Columns11" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Inserted Integer-Division4",{{"Integer-Division", "Hour Bin 2"}}),
    #"Inserted Integer-Division5" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns11", "Integer-Division", each Number.IntegerDivide([Minute], 30), Int64.Type),
    #"Multiplied Column" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Inserted Integer-Division5", {{"Integer-Division", each _ * 30, type number}}),
    #"Renamed Columns12" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Multiplied Column",{{"Integer-Division", "Minute Bin 30"}}),
    #"Inserted Integer-Division6" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns12", "Integer-Division", each Number.IntegerDivide([Minute], 15), Int64.Type),
    #"Multiplied Column1" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Inserted Integer-Division6", {{"Integer-Division", each _ * 15, type number}}),
    #"Renamed Columns13" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Multiplied Column1",{{"Integer-Division", "Minute Bin 15"}}),
    #"Inserted Integer-Division7" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns13", "Integer-Division", each Number.IntegerDivide([Minute], 10), Int64.Type),
    #"Multiplied Column2" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Inserted Integer-Division7", {{"Integer-Division", each _ * 10, type number}}),
    #"Renamed Columns14" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Multiplied Column2",{{"Integer-Division", "Minute Bin 10"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns14"
```

Thanks and let me know anything I can try.

Comment: You should be able to control this in PowerBI, for the field in question choose "Modeling" from the options, under formatting there should be a data Type option where you can select Time and enter your format in the "Display format" section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### note: PowerBI doesn't use `Durations`

- PowerQuery has a `duration` datatype
- But once it hits `DAX`, `there's no` duration`datatype. It automatically converts to a`decimal` for the number of seconds.
- You can use a **measure to render** that decimal in the standard duration format

> Which I can't change on the Power BI Side.

### Possible Duration Formats

[Duration.FromText() says `durations` can use these formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/duration-fromtext):

(All ranges are inclusive)

```
(-)hh:mm(:ss(.ff))
(-)ddd(.hh:mm(:ss(.ff)))
```

where

```
ddd: Number of days.
hh: Number of hours, between 0 and 23.
mm: Number of minutes, between 0 and 59.
ss: Number of seconds, between 0 and 59.
ff: Fraction of seconds, between 0 and 9999999.
```

### See also

- [Custom Format() strings in DAX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/format-function-dax#custom-datetime-format-examples)